# Binding a ComboBox's SelectedItem or SelectedValue which resides inside a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I have a DataGrid. Let it have two columns name and Gender :

```
<DataGrid............>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, RelativeSource.........}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Age">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, RelativeSource.........}" >
                    <sys:String> Male </sys:String>
                    <sys:String> Female </sys:String>
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Now When I run the program, and suppose I have 5 rows in the DataGrid, thenwhen I select male in any row e.g. 3rd row, then all the combobox's SelectedItem becomes Male. How can I avoid this?

When my program runs I have only 1 row, But when I add more rows it looks like :

[image]

When I try to select Female in any ComboBox :

[image]

When I select Female in any ComboBox :

[image]

I know that my Binding is Incorrect, so I am facing such a problem, but can anybody explain me the ComboBox's SelectedItem Binding inside a DataGrid?

Comment: DataGrid is a Control.

Comment: Could you show the entire definition of `SelectedItem` binding? And what is the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid?

Comment: `Selected` property resides where?

Comment: @RohitVats `Selected` Property resides in `GroupsViewModel`.

Comment: So, you are binding all rows with same property. You should bind with the property in underlying source if you want it to be set individually for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to bind List and you have ComboBoxItem objects as items. Set your ComboBox **SelectedValuePath="Content"** like this

```
 <ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" ....... >
                    <sys:String> Male </sys:String>
                    <sys:String> Female </sys:String>
  </ComboBox>
```